# Validating a form in a get request, how?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

in my way of perfectionism, I'm here to ask more questions about the not-so-well-documented class-based views.

I spend like 5 hours learning about class-based views, lurking into the code and I got a question.

Maybe what I'm trying to do is stupid, and if so, just say that.

I will put a simple example:

```
class SearchFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'search/search.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SearchForm(self.request.GET or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.mystuff = Stuff.objects.filter(title__icontains=form.cleaned_data['query'])[:10]

        return super(SearchFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is a perfect valid class (it is, right?).

You have a form, and you make a GET request with a query parameter.

Works like a charm.

But lets imagine... I validate the query input to prevent some type of attack and I see that the query is malicious so I put a validation error.

With the old functions, I have a form instance (empty) and I put data in it and validation errors if needed. I always return that instance, if empty (first request) or if it filled with errors (the case of the malicious query).

The problem is with class-based views. In my get method I work with an extra instance of *SearchForm* so if I put validation stuff would be there and if I call *get* on the *father* it will use the instance on "form_class" that would be empty.

So, I think that there should be a way where I use the same form always, I mean: I call the request method, I pick the form_class (not create a new form), pass the data, validate and the father will return that form with the validation stuff.

Im not sure if I explained this correctly. So in short, Im creating a copy of the form in the get but I return the *father get* who have another copy that will be empty, so my when I display the template, there will be no errors because the form sended is empty.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `super(SearchFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)` renders its own form and own context. It's only a 3 line view function, so you should really be overriding what you need to change its behavior.

```
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SearchForm(self.request.GET or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.mystuff = Stuff.objects.filter(title__icontains=form.cleaned_data['query'])[:10]

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

---

Update: alternate idea if you'd like to continue using the super call

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     self.form = SearchForm(self.request.GET or None)
     if self.form.is_valid():
         self.mystuff = Stuff.objects.filter(title__icontains=form.cleaned_data['query'])[:10]

     return super(SearchFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)


def get_form(self, form_class):
    """
    Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
    """
    return getattr(self, 'form', None) or form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

Comment: Was one of my ideas but I think that is not good because we are broking the FormView, I mean, you have your form_class attribute to display an empty form, to validate the form... but if I dont call the father get, none of those will work, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I don't see how it breaks the FormView - it validates on GET and a POST would proceed as usual. If you really want to use the parent `get` function, you could override `form_class` to return self.form if self.form exists, then in your get function define self.form.

Comment: Well, I prefer the first alternative, the second one is more hacky one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the fact that Django class based views only populate the form kwargs if the HTTP method is POST or PUT:

```
class FormMixin(object):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Returns the keyword arguments for instanciating the form.
        """
        kwargs = {'initial': self.get_initial()}
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            kwargs.update({
                'data': self.request.POST,
                'files': self.request.FILES,
            })
        return kwargs
```

I found this a bit peculiar also, since I have on occasion used a form in a GET request (eg. a "search" form), which needed to perform some basic validation. I just override the get_form_kwargs() method on such views, to also populate the kwargs['data'] item, even when the HTTP method is GET.